# What Icon Would be Appropriate for the Highest Authority User

Tags: icons, administration

Say I'm showing buttons and next to certain people (the super admins), what would be the best icon to convey this meaning?

Currently I'm using a star icon, which definitely works, but I'm just wondering if there is anything that could be more fitting, and is more of a standard in this area.

Comment: Questions requesting Icon Suggestions are off topic. While the subject of icons is on topic, there's very little value in soliciting suggestions for a specific icon in a specific context. See [this meta post](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/629/is-it-time-to-put-an-end-to-icon-for-x-questions%22)  for more information about this topic.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I wasn't sure how the guidelines for this specific stack exchange community were run

Comment: Brian, not your fault. This is a major UX problem with StackExchange itself, because the site doesn't do a good job of communicating guidelines!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using a Crown icon to give that more human feelings since you are assigning that icon to a person. A super admin is the king!

[image]

Comment: As someone commented on my original post, this was sort of opinionated and probably not within the guidelines of this community, but even so, this was exactly what I was looking for, and I hope that this helps someone in the future regardless. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy that you liked that :)

Comment: UX (and design) is a language. Keeping that language consistent is key to good UX. I appreciate the question and this answer. I don't think it's off topic at all. I look forward to seeing this 'language' applied everywhere so we can all communicate intention visually and consistently. Cheers!